# firebase security rule for nested data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following data structure

```
{
  "users": {
    "uid": {
      "priv": {
        "eid": "eid"
      }
    }
  }
}



{
  "entity": {
    "eid": {
      "priv": {},
      "pub": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Now my requirement is - any user can create an entity if it does not have one entity_id in the "priv" child.
Once an user create an entity, it gets the entity_id under it's priv field.
And the same user can modify the same entity which he has under it's priv field.

One entity can have multiple users!

I have tried with the following rule but it allows any one to modify any entity if it does not have an enity_id(i.e. eid) in priv field.

```
"entity":{ 
  ".write": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/priv/eid').val() == null",
  "$eid":{
      ".read": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/priv/eid').val() == $eid",
        ".write": "!data.exists() || root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/priv/eid').val() == $eid"
    }
}
```

How should I re-write the rules?

Comment: *Note that .read and .write rules shallower in the database override deeper rules* See [https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Comment: That i am aware of @Jay . How can I tweak the rules so that I achieve what I want?